# Javascript Addition calculator

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMxbc.jpg)

how do i create this in html.
when a user enter a value in textbox and click on Addition button then textbox became empty and addition button be disabled. then user enter second value and click on = button that show the result in textbox.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some time [on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what and how to ask.

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand what are you exactly want based on question, however I've prepared a basic fiddle for you that should fix your problem or hopefully gives you and idea:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzg5rfgr/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="userNumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="plus">+</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="enteredNumber"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <span id="result">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascript using jquery:

```
$("#plus").on('click', function(){
  var num = parseInt($("#userNumber").val()); // get the number
  $("#result").html(num + parseInt( $("#result").html()) );
  $("#userNumber").val(null); // empty the input box
  $("#enteredNumber").html(num);

})
```

Comment: i want when a user enter a value in textbox and click on + button then textbox become empty then user will enter second value from the same textbox and click on = button this will show result in textbox.